# Regex Expression in Sparql - Mixed text and numbers

Tags: python, regex, sparql, rdflib

I have some resources that are identified by http://myexample.org/NNNN where NNNN is any number, for example, one resource may be http://myexample.org/9890. I am using SPARQL and Python. To retrieve such resources, along with their descriptions, I have tried the following:

```
 pattern="(http://myexample.org/)(\\d{4})"
 r = myGraph.query('''select distinct ?s ?desc where {?s schema:description ?desc .
                                                        filter(regex(str(?s),pattern)))}''')
```

But I get an error:

```
 Expected {SelectQuery | ConstructQuery | DescribeQuery | AskQuery}, found 'f'  (at char 115)
```

The problem is with my regex expression, as when I remove it, the query works. I also tried

```
 pattern="*\\d{4}$"
```

But also got an error. I am working with RDFLib. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's a good idea to use a site like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/H1XpyL/1) to test your pattern

Comment: https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apidocs/rdflib.namespace.html#rdflib.namespace.Namespace

Comment: Yes, I have all the namespaces, and queries without regex work.  The problem is with my both regex expressions. Can't seem to figure the error out

Comment: 1) I'm wondering how your current example code should pass the Python string `pattern` into the SPARQL query string? I mean, you neither use a Python f-String nor do a `.format` - so, how is the pattern interpolated here? Also, your string is missing the quotes then -  2) All you currently do is to run an illegal SPARQL query as the `pattern` has to be a string - i.e. in the query there must be quotes around the pattern. It should be 3) there is also one closing bracket to many

Comment: it must be `filter(regex(str(?s),"pattern"))` and then you should read again about how to interpolate a Python variable into the string

Comment: also, depending on the REGEX flavor, `\d` might not be supported - in that case, just use the alternative `[0-9]`